# Javascript match characters and add space between

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which will detect Chinese characters:

```
function test(){
    var str= '黑色大衣';
    var re1 = new RegExp("^[\u4E00-\uFA29]*$"); //Chinese character range 
    alert(str + ' ' + re1.test(str));
}
test();
```

which you can test here http://jsfiddle.net/of79z9gg/

Right now I have strings like this:

```
this is some English text中文字幕
```

I need a way to detect when the above string has Chinese characters, and insert a space between the English and Chinese characters. Like this:

```
this is some English text 中文字幕
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this. So my question is, how do I detect and then inser the space between the English and Chinese characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this problem other way round.

1. Detect ASCII letters and
2. Insert a space after the captured group.

You can do:

```
var s = 'this is some English text中文字幕';
s = s.replace(/([\x00-\xFF]+)/g, "$1 ");
//=> this is some English text 中文字幕
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to avoid inserting a trailing space then this **lookahead based regex**:

```
var s = 'this is some English text中文字幕 abcd'
s = s.replace(/([\x00-\xFF]+)(?=[^\x00-\xff])/g, "$1 ");
//=> "this is some English text 中文字幕 abcd"
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Works perfectly, I'll accept your answer asap once the time limit has expired :)